# titleForHeaderInSection not being called when implementing UITableViewDataSource protocol

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am setting a `UITableView` with sections. The `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method is being called properly and is returning the right result (in my case 3) but the `titleForHeaderInSection` is not being called at all, and the resulting tableview contains the rows but no sections.

Is there a way to make sure this method gets called by the tableview?

Here is the implementation:

```
- (NSString *) titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{        
    NSString *sectionHeader = nil;

    if (section == 0) 
    {
        sectionHeader = @"Alpha";
    }
    if (section == 1) 
    {
        sectionHeader = @"Beta";
    }
    if (section == 2) 
    {
        sectionHeader = @"Gamma";
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", sectionHeader);

    return sectionHeader;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method signature is `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` your method is is missing the first parameter `tableView` and will not get called.